# Why is "Remove from this list" not working when trying to remove project from Visual Studios Recent projects list?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

How can I permanently clear projects and solutions from the "Recent" list? It is showing several solutions that either have been deleted and no longer exist, or are for reference only and are not to be used. These projects show up both when I right click the Visual Studio icon in the Task Bar, and if I go to File - Recent Files in Visual Studio.

I have already tried right clicking them and selecting "Remove from this list." At first they do disappear, but very soon Visual Studio just starts showing them again anyways.

To me this seems like a bug in Visual Studio. Is there any way to just force a reset on this?

I would prefer to individually remove the ones that no longer exist, but I would be ok with wiping out the entire list and starting fresh.

The only solution that I can find related to this is the suggestion to use the Clear Recent extension. But that extension is not supported by VS 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out this was caused by a bug with Windows, not with Visual Studio.

1. Open the Settings app by clicking on the Start menu and selecting Settings.
2. Click on the Personalization category.
3. Select the Start tab on the left side of the window.
4. Toggle off the option labeled Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar1

This should clear the recent list that is shown when you right-click on the Visual Studio icon in the Taskbar.